# Linq - vb.net select a column based on a variable

Tags: linq, vb.net

We are returning a set of data from a table and need to select a column based on a variable

Code is

```
Dim columnNo as Integer = 1

Dim rs as IEnumerable(Of Object) = db.ImportTable

For each rsRow in rs 
Dim columnF1 = rsRow.f1 'where the field name is f1 (this works fine)
Dim columnVariable = rsRow."f" & columnNo 'This line fails
```

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: What do you mean by "this line fails"? If you get an error, paste the exact error you're getting

Comment: @sinelaw: In this case I think it is pretty obvious.  You can't reference a property name in that way.

Comment: @mellamokb true, but that's no way to ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small performance hit, you can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163750.aspx):

```
rsRow.GetType().GetProperty("f" & columnNo).GetValue(rsRow)
```

This dynamically looks up the property by name, and then reflects the value for that property on the given variable.  Note that this will throw exceptions at runtime if the property name is invalid.

Comment: if `rsRow` doesn't have a property `("f" & columnno)` => evaluates to f3 (Example) , Then Object reference error will occur at that point right.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Correct, because the result of `GetProperty` will be `Null`.